# how to generate local keys from the view using I18n? (rather than from an existing yml file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

I created a rails app using I18n. I used the method I18n.t with the helper (e.g. `t('.hello')`), but I have not created the relevant local keys in the en.yml file.

Using `i18n-tasks add-missing` only adds keys which exist already in other yml file.

Is there a way to generate all the local keys from the I18n.t method? For instance, if it finds `t('.hello')` in a view of flats, it would generate in the en.yml file:

```
 en:
    flats:
        show:
            hello: 'hello'
```

Comment: This is what `i18n-tasks add-missing` does. It adds all the missing keys used in your views as well.

Comment: it seems that it only adds the 'keys missing' from another yml file, not the ones missing from the view.

Comment: It does both, see the readme

Comment: What is the path to your view file, its contents, and i18n-tasks config?